# Xamarin Forms Android video compress

Tags: android, xamarin, video, xamarin.forms, compression

Part of my application (Xamarin Forms - crossplatform) needs to reduce the size of video files. iOS does it itself, but Android doesn't. For photos I do it like this:

```
public byte[] CompressImage(byte[] imageData, int imageQuality, int imageWidth, int imageHeight)
        {
            int smallToBigWidth = imageWidth / 2;
            int smallToBigHeight = imageHeight / 2;
            Bitmap originalImage = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
            float proportions = (float)imageHeight / (float)originalImage.Height;
            float newWidth = (float)originalImage.Width * proportions;
            originalImage = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(originalImage, (int)newWidth, imageHeight, false);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                originalImage.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, imageQuality, ms);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

But how do you do it with a video so that when you select a file from the gallery, you get a reduced version without saving the new file on your phone? I download the file using MediaPicker

```
var file = await MediaPicker.PickVideoAsync ();
```

and gets a file of the FileResult type, and this is the type I would like to achieve after compression. Anyone have any ideas? I must have looked everywhere and nothing.

Comment: it took me 10s to find dozens of similar questions - https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin+android+api+compress+video+site%253Astackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

For Android, you could use `Transcoder`.  https://github.com/natario1/Transcoder

You could also refer to sample: https://github.com/leye0/XamarinAndroidFFmpeg

Comment: But how to use it? I'm trying to use Transcoder or LightCompressor and I need to use ITranscoderListener (in Transcoder) or ICompressionListener (in LightCompressor). When I create a class that implements this interface, I get an error "Specific cast is invalid". Help me please